# Doubts to understand C-APDU and R-APDU commands

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, emv

I began to study basic notions of APDU command and response these days and i'm in a doubt about the use of the Lc and data track and his meaning. 
For example, if i write a command like: 
00 A4 04 00 0E 31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00
I'd say that his (correct me case if i'm wrong)

- CLA = is equal 00
- INS = A4 that is SELECT
- P1 = 04 by his first record name
- P2 = 00 as default
- Lc = 0E = exact length of 14 Bytes
- Data = where it's my doubt
- Le = 00 as default, and if it was equal another value what happens?

My doubt is about understand the clearly meaning of the Lc (exact command length), data and Le (maximum response length), how am i do to know what is this data instruction mean? and am i supposed to turn it into a text?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

6F 15 84 0E 31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 03 88 01 01 90 00
would be parsed as

```
 
6F File Control Information (FCI) Template
16 Length in hex
    84 Dedicated File (DF) Name
    0E Length in hex
        315041592E5359532E4444463031    =>1PAY.SYS.DDF01
    A5 File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
    03 length in hex
        88 Short File Identifier (SFI)
        01 length in hex
            01
    90 00 Successful operation
```

Simply, you can use [this](https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/) to parse your response TPDUs :-)

Comment: @MichaelRoland The first part of the question CAPDU was already answered. Mine is for the second part, how to interpret the R-APDU asked as - "and at the R-APDU i already know that the SW1 and SW2 is responsible to show the process state and i don't know how to interpret the data too like at the C-APDU."  The question was edited after I answered as you can see in the edit history. That is the reason answer is accepted by user.

Comment: Still the R-APDU that you (more or less) arbitrarily chose for your example wasn't mentioned in the question (nor in any of the previous revisions).

Comment: illustration using an eg. is much easier to understand. or is it just for me?

Comment: Your "example" illustrates just how to interpret one specific resonse format. It does not even try to illustrate the format of arbitrary R-APDUs. Hence, your post does not seem to even try to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

`Lc = 0E` means there is 14 bytes of data following so:

`31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31` is your data (14 bytes). When you interpret it as ASCII values you get the string `1PAY.SYS.DDF01`.

Field `Le` indicates how many bytes are expected (00 = maximum bytes) as response.

Comment: @Ito You should definitely select this as the accepted answer!